# Independence and Conditional Expectations

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-expectation

I have a simple question.

It is known that, if X and Y are independent, then

$\mathbb{E}[X | Y] = E[X]$

where X and Y are just random variables.

However, is the converse true? i.e. Given that $\mathbb{E}[X | Y] = E[X]$, can I assume they are independent?

Thanks

Comment: And a sufficient condition would be $\mathbb{E}[1_{\{X\in B\}}| Y] = \mathbb{E}[1_{\{X\in B\}}]$ for each Borel set $B$ of $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume $\mathsf E(X\mid Y)=\mathsf E(X)$ , then $\mathsf {Var}(X,Y)~{=\mathsf E(\mathsf E(XY\mid Y))-\mathsf E(X)\mathsf E(Y) = 0}$.   Therefore $X$ and $Y$ are not *linearly correlated*.

Independent random variables are not linearly correlated, however the converse is not necessarily so.   Linearly uncorrelated random variables *need not* be independent.   Counterexamples can easily be found.   Here is one.

Assume $X\sim\mathcal U\{-2,-1,1,2\}$ and $Y=X^2$ surely.   $X$ and $Y$ are clearly dependent, but you will find that $\mathsf E(X\mid Y)=\mathsf E(X)$.

---